# Android Create Calendar Event always as Birthday

Tags: java, c#, android, mobile, xamarin

I have a strange issue when I create a calendar event programmatically
its always noted as Birthday Calendar (type) I don't have any clue why its noted like that.

My code I use is as below: Xamarin C#

```
ContentResolver cr = ((Activity)Forms.Context).ContentResolver;
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
String eventUriString = "content://com.android.calendar/events";

//Insert Events in the calendar...
values.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.CalendarId, 1);
values.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Title, title);
values.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Status, 1);
values.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Description, description);
values.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtstart, GetDateTimeMS(year, month, day, hour, minute));
values.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtend, GetDateTimeMS(year, month, day, hour, minute));
values.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.AllDay, allday ? "1" : "0");
values.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.HasAlarm, hasalarm ? "1" : "0");
values.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.EventColor, Android.Graphics.Color.Green);
values.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.EventTimezone, "GMT+" + zone + ":00");
values.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.EventEndTimezone, "GMT+" + zone + ":00");
cr.Insert(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(eventUriString), values);
```

Please does someone has any tips or ideas which can point me to the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question answered below is old please refer to [Pkosta's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6696517/pkosta) answer which provides more accurate answer ...

You have to put CalendarId value as 3 instead of 1 which is default birthday calendar. 
e.g.

```
 values.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.CalendarId, 1);
```

change it to

```
values.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.CalendarId, 3);
```

It solved the same issue for me.

Answer (score 14):

Some devices uses calendar id = 1 for birthdays but generally not. So to get the correct calendar id for particular device (corresponding to the email id configured with calendar app), use below code:

```
private int getCalendarId(Context context){

  Cursor cursor = null;
  ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
  Uri calendars = CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI;

  String[] EVENT_PROJECTION = new String[] {
        CalendarContract.Calendars._ID,                           // 0
        CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME,                  // 1
        CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME,         // 2
        CalendarContract.Calendars.OWNER_ACCOUNT,                 // 3
        CalendarContract.Calendars.IS_PRIMARY                     // 4
};

  int PROJECTION_ID_INDEX = 0;
  int PROJECTION_ACCOUNT_NAME_INDEX = 1;
  int PROJECTION_DISPLAY_NAME_INDEX = 2;
  int PROJECTION_OWNER_ACCOUNT_INDEX = 3;
  int PROJECTION_VISIBLE = 4;

  cursor = contentResolver.query(calendars, EVENT_PROJECTION, null, null, null);

  if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    String calName;
    long calId = 0;
    String visible;

    do {
        calName = cursor.getString(PROJECTION_DISPLAY_NAME_INDEX);
        calId = cursor.getLong(PROJECTION_ID_INDEX);
        visible = cursor.getString(PROJECTION_VISIBLE);
        if(visible.equals("1")){
            return (int)calId;
        }
        Log.e("Calendar Id : ", "" + calId + " : " + calName + " : " + visible);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());

    return (int)calId;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

**Point to note :** IS_PRIMARY_COLOUM which returns 1 in case of email id and not for bithdays and holidays.

Please refer: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.CalendarColumns.html#IS_PRIMARY for details.

Comment: So finally after wasting hours and hours to find the solution for my issue...finally your code solved my issue....thank you so much.

Comment: requires android.permission.READ_CALENDAR

Answer (score 5):

[Pkosta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6696517/pkosta) is pointing in the right direction.
You have to take the first calendar that is both `VISIBLE` and `IS_PRIMARY`.

```
long calId = 0;
String selection = CalendarContract.Calendars.VISIBLE + " = 1 AND " 
+ CalendarContract.Calendars.IS_PRIMARY + " = 1";

Uri calendarUri = CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI;
Cursor cur = cr.query(calendarUri, null, selection, null, null);

if (cur != null && cur.moveToFirst()) {
  Get the field values
  calID = cur.getLong(CalendarContract.Calendars._ID);
}
if (cur != null) {
  cur.close();
}

return calId;
```

Comment: cur.getLong(CalendarContract.Calendars._ID); this is erroneous. It should be -
        int index = cur.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Calendars._ID);
        calId = cur.getLong(index);